# api coming twice in URL "api/AuthenticationAPI/logout"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

As a convention in our project, we have named all our API controller classes as `AuthenticationApiController` as opposed to controller's in MVC `AuthenticationController`.

But now when API gets invoked, we have to call it like `/api/authenticationapi/logout`.

Thought not a problem, but I am not liking that "api" word is coming twice in the URL.

Is there a way, I can customize the route which is defined as `[Route("api/[controller]")]` to remove api from controller name when URL is getting added to route table.

**Note: looking for a generic way, rather than hardcoding the name on every api controller.

Comment: Of course you can. you can add it on controller function and make request with that url.

Comment: but then that wont be generic... here i created a BaseApiController and derived all controller from that... so that I dont have to do it on all controllers

Comment: Then.. there are two ways to add controller : webapiController(this use api/~) and MVC controller(not include `api`)

Comment: And also you can setup WebApiConfig.cs

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Url Rewriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.0#url-rewrite) and refer to my demo which uses asp.net core 3.0:

1.Create RewriterRules

```
public class RewriteRules
{
    public static void ReWriteRequests(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var path = request.Path.Value;

        if (path != null)
        {
            var array = path.Split("/");
            if (array[1] == "api" && !array[2].EndsWith("api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                array[2] = array[2] + "api";
                var newPath = String.Join("/", array);
                context.HttpContext.Request.Path = newPath;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

2.Register it in startup Configure method(before `app.UseMvc()` if you use core 2.2)

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
            .Add(RewriteRules.ReWriteRequests)
            );
app.UseRouting();         
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

3.Test

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticationApiController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/TestApi
    [HttpGet("logout")]
    public IEnumerable<string> logout()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
 }
```

Call `/api/authentication/logout` it will comes into the action successfully